# ObjectAnimator on ProgressWheel by Todd-Davies

Tags: android, progress-bar, objectanimator

I am trying to make a ProgressWheel where the color change as the wheel fill up (the wheel start green at 0% and finish red at 100% with all the wheel become red over the time : not a rainbow). 
So I am using an ObjectAnimator, the wheel take the entry color but I cannot manage to make it change color over time...

```
final ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "barColor", Color.GREEN, Color.RED);
animator.setDuration(remainingTime);
animator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
animator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2));
animator.start();
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did this (it comes from another post on StackOverflow):

```
final ObjectAnimator colorAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(progressBar, "barColor", new ArgbEvaluator(), green, red);
colorAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                progressBar.refreshWheel();
        }
});
colorAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());            
colorAnimator.setDuration(remainingTime);
colorAnimator.start();
```

and in ProgressWheel.java

```
public void refreshWheel() {
    setupPaints();
}
```